# Impulse invariance vs. DT representation of a CT system: Where is the inconsistency?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, sampling, continuous-signals, impulse-response

Suppose you have a continuous-time (CT) system $h_c(t)$, bandlimited to $B$. Your goal is to represent the system as a discrete-time (DT) system $h[n]$, sampled at $f_s \leq 2 B$. Clearly $h[n]$ won't be a faithful representation of $h_c(t)$ because we do not satisfy the sampling theorem. But I am interested in the exact relationship between $h_c(t)$ and $h[n]$ in this case. There are two ways to think about this:

#### Representing the CT system as DT one

Based on this question (and answer): [Representing a continuous LTI system as a discrete one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60677/representing-a-continuous-lti-system-as-a-discrete-one), $h[n]$ represents a **low-pass filtered** version of $h_c(t)$:

$$
h[n] = \tilde{h}_c(n T_s) ,\\
\tilde{h}_c(t) = \int h_c(\tau) \operatorname{sinc}\left(t-\tau\right) \operatorname{d}\tau
$$

#### Impulse Invariance

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_invariance, the sampled $h[n]$ corresponds to an **aliased** $h_c(t)$:

$$
H(e^{-j\omega}) = \frac{1}{T_s} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} H_c\left(j\frac{\omega}{T_s} + j\frac{2\pi}{T_s}k \right)
$$

I could take the IDTFT:

$$
h[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} T_s e^{-j2\pi k n} h_c(n T_s)
$$

which is not the same as the low-pass filtered version above.
There no low-pass filtering.

These two approaches seem to give me two different answers on how to relate $h[n]$ and $h_c(t)$ (when sampling theorem is not obeyed).
What is wrong?

Comment: i don't think you're representing the result in the wikipedia article quite faithfully.  and what is "$\omega$" in your bottom equation?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the $\omega$. What is not faithfully represented from the wikipedia article?

Comment: $$ h[n] = T \ h_c(nT) $$

$$ H(e^{j\omega}) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} H_c \left( j\tfrac{\omega}{T} + j\tfrac{2\pi k}{T}\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

The *Impulse Invariant* method does not promise to represent the frequency response of the  continuous-time system as a lowpass version.  What the Impulse Invariant method does is frequency-alias the frequency response by sliding it by multiples of the sampling frequency and adding up all of the translated copies.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing *wrong*, per se.  There's two different methods, each of which represents an approximation of the continuous-time system in discrete time.

*Each one is an approximation*.  You can't get around that.

In a real system design that starts with some continuous-time prototype, it's up to the system designer to decide what is the most appropriate approximation* to use.

* There is exactly one case that I know of where you can make an exact discrete-time model of a continuous-time system.  But that's in the restricted case where you're exciting the continuous-time system with a ZOH (i.e., a DAC) driven at the sampling rate, then sampling the continuous-time system's output.  This is *very handy* for control system design, because you can exactly model the behavior of a continuous-time plant from the perspective of a discrete-time controller.  But it otherwise doesn't have a lot of application.